# Message: Expected identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why this error? I think that I has closed all brackets. This is the code:

```
  int i=0;

    while(i<count){

    if([[ageMatch rangeOfString:age].location != NSNotFound] && [[glassesSex rangeOfString:gender].location !=NSNotFound] && [[faceMatch rangeOfString:shape].location != NSNotFound]  ){ //Expected identifier
            [arrayNuovo insertObject:dictionary atIndex:i];

        }
        i++;
     }
```

Comment: This is not Smalltalk. The boolean operator is *not* a message send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

> ```
> while(i < count){
> if(([ageMatch rangeOfString:age].location != NSNotFound) && ([glassesSex rangeOfString:gender].location !=NSNotFound) && ([faceMatch rangeOfString:shape].location != NSNotFound)  ){ //Expected identifier
>         [arrayNuovo insertObject:dictionary atIndex:i];
>             }
>     i++;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

you should change

```
if([[ageMatch rangeOfString:age].location != NSNotFound] && [[glassesSex rangeOfString:gender].location !=NSNotFound] && [[faceMatch rangeOfString:shape].location != NSNotFound]  )
```

To

```
 if([ageMatch rangeOfString:age].location != NSNotFound && 
    [glassesSex rangeOfString:gender].location !=NSNotFound && 
    [faceMatch rangeOfString:shape].location != NSNotFound  )
```

When you do a boolean test, you do it like `[string rangeOfString:age].location != NSNotFound` and dont include them in [ and ]